# Setting status of Selenium test using TestNG + Gradle not working

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, gradle, testng

I've added a listener for taking screenshots, dumping the page source in to a file, and setting certain failed test statuses to SKIP. The screenshot and DOM dump operations work but my test is still listed as a failure in the report.

I'm using Gradle running Selenium 2.x and TestNG.

Here is my listener code:

```
package com.xmatters.testng;

import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
import com.xmatters.webdriver.tests.BaseTest;

public class Listener extends TestListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationFailure(ITestResult itr) {
        BaseTest.writeSource(itr.getName()); //writes source to a text file (useful for hidden stack traces)
        BaseTest.takeScreenshot(itr.getName()); //captures and saves a screenshot
        System.out.println("DEBUG: Failed test result getName() = " + itr.getName());
        if (itr.getName().contains("createTestData")) {
            System.out.println("DEBUG: Skip condition met - createTestData");
            itr.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP); //sets failed configurations to skipped, re-run logic will be added
            Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(itr);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {
        BaseTest.writeSource(tr.getName()); //writes source to a text file (useful for hidden stack traces)
        BaseTest.takeScreenshot(tr.getName()); //captures and saves a screenshot
        System.out.println("DEBUG: Failed test result getName() = " + tr.getName());
        if (tr.getName().contains("createTestData")) {
            System.out.println("DEBUG: Skip condition met - createTestData");
            tr.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP); //sets failed configurations to skipped, re-run logic will be added
            Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(tr);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.38.0"
    compile "org.testng:testng:5.14.10"
    testCompile('org.uncommons:reportng:1.1.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.testng'
    }
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.8.2"
    compile "com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:1.8.1"
}

//initialize thread count variable for parallel testing and default to 1
def threadCount = System.getProperty("MAXTHREADS", "1")

tasks.withType(Test) {
    maxParallelForks = 1
    forkEvery = 1000
    ignoreFailures = false

    // Pass all system properties to the tests
    systemProperties = System.getProperties()

    // Makes the standard streams (err and out) visible at console when running tests
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

    exclude '**/tasks/'

    classpath += configurations.testCompile
}

task firefox(type: Test) {
    maxParallelForks = Integer.valueOf(threadCount) //default is 1 if not specified
    testLogging.events "started"
    testLogging {
        events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
        exceptionFormat "full" // default is "short"
    }
    useTestNG() {
        excludeGroups 'chrome', 'broken'
        useDefaultListeners = false
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }

    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/firefox")
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/firefox")

    systemProperties.BROWSER = System.getProperty('BROWSER', 'firefox')

    exclude '**/selenium/'
    exclude '**/setupscripts/'
}

task chrome(type: Test) {
    maxParallelForks = Integer.valueOf(threadCount) //default is 1 if not specified
    testLogging {
        events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
        exceptionFormat "full"
    }
    useTestNG() {
        excludeGroups 'broken'
        useDefaultListeners = false;
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }

    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/chrome")
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/chrome")

    systemProperties.BROWSER = System.getProperty('BROWSER', 'chrome')

    exclude '**/selenium/'
    exclude '**/setupscripts/'
}

task internetExplorer(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        excludeGroups 'chrome', 'broken'
        useDefaultListeners = false;
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/internetExplorer")
    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/internetExplorer")

    systemProperties.BROWSER = System.getProperty('BROWSER', 'internetExplorer')

    exclude '**/selenium/'
    exclude '**/setupscripts/'
}

task applylicense(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = false;
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }

    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/applyLicense")
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/applyLicense")

    scanForTestClasses = false
    include '**/setupscripts/ApplyLicense.class'
}

task uatsetup(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = false;
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }

    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/uatSetup")
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/uatSetup")

    scanForTestClasses = false
    include '**/setupscripts/UatSetup.class'
}

task restsetup(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = false;
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }

    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/restSetup")
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/restSetup")

    scanForTestClasses = false
    include '**/setupscripts/RestSetup.class'
}

task soapsetup(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = false;
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }

    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/soapSetup")
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/soapSetup")

    scanForTestClasses = false
    include '**/setupscripts/SoapSetup.class'
}

task selenium(type: Test) {
    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/selenium")
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/selenium")

    include '**/selenium/'
    exclude '**/webdriver/'
    exclude '**/*$*', '**/Abstract*'
    exclude '**/messagepanel/'
    exclude '**/propertylibrary/'
}

javadoc() {
    title = "xMod Page Objects API"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.7'
}
```

And here is the Jenkins console output for the test I wanted to be marked as a SKIP:

```
com.xmatters.webdriver.tests.FormPermissionsTest.createTestData STARTED

com.xmatters.webdriver.tests.FormPermissionsTest.createTestData FAILED
    org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out loading CompanyAdministratorsChangeWebLoginScreen
    Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.selector: form#webLoginDetailsForm
    Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
    System info: host: 'vic-apod-build', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-57-generic', java.version: '1.6.0_18'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
    System info: host: 'vic-apod-build', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-57-generic', java.version: '1.6.0_18'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:259)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:228)
        at com.xmatters.webui.pages.AbstractPageObject.waitForPageToLoad(AbstractPageObject.java:42)
        at com.xmatters.webui.pages.AbstractPageObject.<init>(AbstractPageObject.java:31)
        at com.xmatters.webui.pages.AbstractPageObject.<init>(AbstractPageObject.java:23)
        at com.xmatters.webui.pages.home.admin.companies.CompanyAdministratorsChangeWebLoginScreen.<init>(CompanyAdministratorsChangeWebLoginScreen.java:15)
        at com.xmatters.webui.pages.home.admin.companies.CompanyAdministratorsDetailsScreen.clickSave(CompanyAdministratorsDetailsScreen.java:67)
        at com.xmatters.webdriver.tasks.Users.createCompanyAdmin(Users.java:50)
        at com.xmatters.webdriver.tests.FormPermissionsTest.createTestData(FormPermissionsTest.java:62)

Gradle test STANDARD_OUT
    DEBUG: Failed test result getName() = createTestData
    DEBUG: Skip condition met - createTestData
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following code:

```
if (tr.getName().contains("createTestData")) {
        tr.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP); //sets failed configurations to skipped, re-run logic will be added
        Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(tr);
}
```

My example:

```
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    result.setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS); // make all FAILED tests a SUCCESS
    Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);
}
```

With this code the tests run result is the following

```
PASSED: shouldShowHelpPageForNewQueryPage
PASSED: shouldShowHelpPageForViewPage
PASSED: shouldShowInactiveCreateNewQuery

===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

If I remove the code from onTestFailure(), the result will be as follows:

```
FAILED: shouldShowHelpPageForNewQueryPage
java.lang.NullPointerException
...

FAILED: shouldShowHelpPageForViewPage
java.lang.NullPointerException
...

FAILED: shouldShowInactiveCreateNewQuery
java.lang.NullPointerException
...


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 3, Failures: 3, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 3, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Hi Vlad, thanks for the recommendation. I'm getting an unresolved symbol issue with `result` in the line: `Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);` Was that meant to have the ITestResult object passed in?

Comment: @Darwin Forgot to change the variable name... Updated the code in the response

Comment: Cool, that's what I was trying. Appears to be an issue with me using an older version of TestNG and updating it is causing problems. I'll get that sorted out and then give this another shot.

Comment: Ok, I added some debug code in to my test and it appears that Gradle is still interpreting and logging the test as a fail and the result is not getting changed. The logic seems to be run after the fact and has no impact on the actual report. Added more info to my question above.

Comment: This code works fine for me if I implement [onTestFailure()](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestListener.html#onTestFailure\(org.testng.ITestResult\)) method of ITestListener.

Comment: Hmm, it may have something to do with my configuration then. I'm running this using a Gradle wrapper through Jenkins. It could be possible that it's changing the TestNG result but not the one reported back to Gradle. If you get a chance, would you be able to provide an example of your console output when you run your version?

Comment: Ok, will do tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. It looks like what is happening in my case is that the TestNG results ARE getting changed, but Gradle's output is displaying the failure before the handling is done. I've been using Gradle for reporting since TestNG has poor support for parallel testing but I think I'll have to find a workaround to somehow keep TestNG from overwriting itself and aggregate the results.

Comment: @DarwinAllen Too bad it does not solve your actual problem... I see that in your code you extend the TestListenerAdapter class which is "A simple ITestListener adapter that stores all the tests that were run", while I implement the ITestListener. It is unlikely to be the reason, but you never know... And why don't you try to run those tests from the IDE and see what test results look like there? Good luck!

Comment: Tried from my IDE (IntelliJ 13), same result. It seems that in Gradle's eyes, the test is a failure, while the TestNG report looks just fine. Looks like I'll need to find a way to get Gradle to listen to TestNG's status instead of just immediately treating any assertion as a failed test.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was only calling setStatus() and was not calling Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result); and because of that my report was always showing all failed though I was trying to skip TCs if ran multiple times upon failure. Thanks! I am going to test out my final code.